# Route not rendering component when Url changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have the following ProductThumbnail component where as i click on the link it updates the URL and changes the route to redirect toward ProductDesc component. It generates the URL /productDescRedux/itemId properly.

```
const ProductThumbnail = (props) => {
 const itemId = props.product
 return(
  <div>
    <Link to={`/productDescRedux/${itemId.id}`}>
     <div>
      <h1>{props.product.headline}</h1>
      <img src={props.product.images[0].imagesUrls.entry[1].url} alt="Thumbnail small pic"/>
      <p></p>
     </div>
   </Link>
  </div>
 )
}

ProductThumbnail.propTypes = {
 product: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default ProductThumbnail;
```

However despite URL changes, **it does not call the component ProductDesc** and i have to reload the page to display the component ProductDesc. Below the routes and the component ProductDesc

```
const Routes = function(){
 return(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ Container }>
     <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
     <Route path="/productredux" component={ App } >
      <IndexRoute component={ ProductsGrid }/>
      <Route path="/productDescRedux/:id" component={ ProductDesc } />
     </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={ NotFound } />
   </Route>
  </Router>
 </Provider>
 )
}

export default Routes;

const ProductDesc = ()=>({
 render(){
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <p>Yeah</p>
   </div>
  )
 }
})
```

And here for completion the App component which uses connect() as well as the Main component

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    products:state.products
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators,dispatch);
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

//in a different file

```
const Main = (props) => ({
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
          {React.cloneElement(props.children, this.props)}
        </div>
      )
    }
})

export default Main;
```

So I don't see why when changing the URL , routing is not calling the component ProductDesc. any insight ?

Comment: where is `ProductThumbnail` declared in route hierarchy? Is it a child of  `ProductsGrid `?

Comment: Yes I'm calling it in ProductsGrid as a child

Comment: could you include you `App` component code too? or provide your code in a gist or jsbin. It will help others understand your issue better

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue on the Main component which is the parent of all. I needed

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
```

instead of

```
{React.cloneElement(props.children, this.props)}
```

[Ref issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727758/only-root-route-is-being-rendered-indexroute-not-rendering-components?rq=1)